# getting value from wp meta value using custom php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I'm trying to get `typedtest` text from a mysql result:

```
a:1:{s:5:"typed";s:9:"typedtest";}
```

How can i get the `s:9 value` from above using php?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want the word `typedtest` as your result? Is the result always in this exact format?

Comment: yes Nick that's right, and also the format is same just changes like: a:1:{s:5:"typed";s:24:"hey is it signed? teped?";}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i found.

```
$array = explode('"', $signature_value);
//print_r($array);
echo $array[3];
```